# Memory corruption/structure reordering on OSX + llvm/libc++

Tags: c++, macos, llvm, memory-corruption

After finally getting a cross-platform project to compile, I am having the weirdest errors on OSX. The program crashes in different ways (but may sometimes survive to show it's ui). Stepping through with the XCode debugger I see multiple places where values of subobjects *change* depending on context. This is literally the problem I have:

```
class third
{
public:
    int some_data;
    void do_something()
    {
    }
    
};

class second
{
public:
    third * thirdPtr;
    
    second()
        : thirdPtr(nullptr)
    {
        thirdPtr = new third();
        printf("second = 0x%X, third = 0x%X", this, thirdPtr);
    }
    
};


class first
{
    second * secondInstance;
    first()
        : secondInstance(nullptr)
    {
        secondInstance = new second();
        printf("second = 0x%X, third = 0x%X", secondInstance, secondInstance->thirdPtr);
        // (maybe) crash
        secondInstance->thirdPtr->do_something();
        
    }
    
};
```

While stepping through, I added a watchpoint to the third pointer. This is an example output:

```
Watchpoint 1 hit:
old value: 0x00000001
new value: 0x00000000

Watchpoint 1 hit:
old value: 0x00000000
new value: 0x04821c34
```

And here's stdout of the program:

```
second = 0x4821C20, third = 0x4821C34
second = 0x4821C20, third = 0x3404821C
```

I have never seen something like this. Obviously the structs are more complex and use inheritance, but nothing else has access or writes to these structs under initialization. I have so many weird glitches and problems in my source code, so I assume this glitch is the problem multiple places. Mind you the source code has run flawlessly for a long time on other platforms, and it faults even in external library code (I use JUCE for the project).

At first I suspected operator new to be bogus, but it seems to have something with the composition of the objects to do. Interestingly, the two different third's seem to have strong similarities.

I'm really at a loss here, I'm ready to conclude that llvm rearranges the layout of the structs between compile units (the classes/structs are in separate files of course).. or something. I assume I'm wrong - but has anyone ever experienced anything like this?

I added the following code.
(inside second constructor):

```
    {
        thirdPtr = new third();
        printf("second = 0x%X, third = 0x%X", this, thirdPtr);
        printf("position = %d", offsetof(second, thirdPtr);
    }
```

(inside first constructor):

```
    {
        secondInstance = new second();
        printf("second = 0x%X, third = 0x%X", secondInstance, secondInstance->thirdPtr);
        printf("position = %d", offsetof(second, thirdptr));
        
    }
```

And it prints:

```
13
16
```

Note: this is the output of the complete structures (ie. not the examples given here).
BUT: The layout of the structures are actually different depending on what compilation/translation unit im in. What the hell is going on here?

So I decided to check alignment as well, this could be the key problem:

stdout from inside second constructor:

```
second = 0x3649090, third = 0x36490A4
offset of third in second = 16
sizeof second = 232
align of third = 4, align of second = 4
```

stdout from inside first constructor:

```
second = 0x3649090, third = 0xA4036490
offset of second in third = 13
sizeof second = 226
align of third 1, align of second 1
```

So it seems alignment is changed in translation units. What can I do to enforce a standard across the whole project?

I managed to get it 'running', as in, it doesn't crash immediately, by applying a **attribute**((packed)) to the second class. But this really doesn't leave me feeling safe, and why do I have to do this? Is there a global setting that manipulates this setting in translation units?

Comment: Are you running on a 64-bit OS? If so, the `printf()`'s might not be reliable since you're passing 64-bit pointers but `%X` would be expecting 32-bit values (I think - I'm not sure if OS X uses the LP64 data model)

Comment: It is on 64-bit os, but it is a 32-bit build. The debugger shows the correct addresses.

Comment: "BUT: The layout of the structures are actually different depending on what compilation/translation unit I'm in"  - this sounds like something is providing a different packing option when one translation unit is being compiled.  Take a close look at the build log.

Comment: I'm not really sure what i should be looking for, i am using no such thing in the source code (packing options) and the two source code files share the same compiler/project settings and are compiled in one go.
Additionally, sizeof() shows a difference of 6 bytes depending on where it is called.

Comment: Packing/alignment definitely looks like it differs from the example, so unless the structure gets redefined, packing/alignment looks like it's modified.  Have you tried inspecting `alignment_of()`?

Comment: Yeah the alignment definately differs. I added another edit with diagnostics from alignment_of(), can you check it out and see if you can make any sense of it?

Comment: @Shaggi: I'd look for any differences in the options used to compile one module vs. the other.  I'm not familiar with llvm's options. With GCC it would be `-fpack-struct`, with MSVC it would be `/Zp`.  Also, a header might have a `#pragma pack` that can change the setting, so an analysis of the headers included might be in order, too (and that's always fun).

Comment: @MichaelBurr YES thats the problem. I edited the solution in. Thank you so much, guys! (turns out llvm silently supports #pragma pack aswell)

Comment: @Shaggi Once you have enough rep, I'd recommend you come back and write you last update as an answer. Glad you found it!

Comment: @MatthewG. Me too. This has been the weirdest issue i've ever had, haha. Yeah i can write an answer for it

Comment: Glad you found it :).  Sorry I missed the response :(.  If you still need the custom packing and you can use C++11, you may want to check out `alignas()`.  It's probably a bit easier to debug, and it's also part of the language spec.

Comment: @Jason neat! - I'm definitely going to use that instead :)

Answer (score 2):

It became evident just how important it is to reset the packing stack when working with user defined packing alignment of structs.

The visual studio compiler and clang's front end for llvm both support the same syntax using #pragma directives which can be studied here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx

In my case, an included header had a mismatching #pragma pack directive like so:

```
    #ifdef __MSVC__
        #pragma pack(push, 1)
    #else
        #pragma pack (push, 1)
    #endif

    ....

    #if defined(__MSVC__)
        #pragma pack(pop)
    #endif
```

The packing stack would be altered by any compiler, but only be restored if msvc++ compiler was used. This left packing alignment of translation units that included this file to be different than the ones that didn't, even though both translation units saw the exact same struct definition. For completeness, here's the (in my case) corrected #pragma directives:

```
    #if defined(__MSVC__) || defined (__LLVM__)
        #pragma pack (push, 1)
    #endif

    #if defined(__MSVC__) || defined (__LLVM__)
        #pragma pack(pop)
    #endif
```

Comment: You may want to consider looking into whether struct layout packing is really necessary at all.

Comment: I only did it in the first case because it was needed :) its a part of some shared C-structs between different languages